# KWin scripting - calling a DBus function with callDBus

Tags: scripts, kde, kwin

So I'm trying to get started with scripting kwin - specifically, I want some minor modifications to the kwin tiling script.

based on the kde docs, I started the desktop shell scripting console with wm console and have put this in -

```
callDBus("org.freedesktop.Notifications", 
         "/org/freedesktop/Notifications/", 
         "org.freedesktop.Notifications", 
         "Notify",
         "app", 0, "", "summary", "test body", [], {}, 0, function() {
    print("called")
})
```

That's literally all of my script. From what I understand, the callDBus is a global function and the params to the Notify method are picked up from qdbusviewer - however, running this script does not produce a notification. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you don't get an answer here, try https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/.

Comment: Posted here after posting on /r/ke :(

Comment: What is the permalink?

Comment: https://redd.it/92vjgo

Comment: One more place to ask is https://www.kubuntuforums.net.